# VBA Excel Save workbook with an option to cancel

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I wrote a code that let's me save a macros enabled workbook from pressing a command button in the userform. It generates a file name and all is perfect but the problem I've run into with saving files via VBA is that if I cancel or close the saving window, it still saves the file but with a file name "FALSE".

Code I have is:

```
Private Sub SaveAs_CommandButton_Click()

'Declare variables
Dim fName As Variant

'Main Function
fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
InitialFileName:="TU_" & UserForm_TVPM.OfferNumber_TextBox.Value & "_" & UserForm_TVPM.Client_TextBox.Value & ".xlsm", _
FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=fName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

End Sub
```

Could someone, please, help me modify the code so that cancelling saving does what is expected (cancel the saving like in any other software)?

Comment: You have the answer below, but for future reference, the Microsoft pages have all the detail on the function, and an example that does exactly what you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private Sub SaveAs_CommandButton_Click()

'Check if all values has been entered
If Not CheckMissingHomeValues Then Exit Sub

'Declare variables
Insert one line of code after fName Save as command to check if fName = False then exit.Below mentioned code has command added.

```
sub
    Dim fName As Variant
    
    'Main Function
    fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:="TU_" & UserForm_TVPM.OfferNumber_TextBox.Value & "_" & UserForm_TVPM.Client_TextBox.Value & ".xlsm", _
    FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")
    If fName = False then exit sub 
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=fName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    
    End Sub
```